# Swift API Call using dataTaskPublisher

Tags: json, swift, api, parsing, networking

Had various success with using dataTaskPublisher and pulling data from APIs.
Issue I'm having is with nested JSON. I can fetch simple JSON but something like the Pokemon API where it has nested JSON is getting me.

Any advise would be great.
The onappear: // fetch completion is the part I'm hung up on.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct Pokemon: Codable {
    var cards: Card
}

struct Card: Codable {
    var id: String
    var name: String
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var requests = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    @State var pokemon: Pokemon
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("card name here")
        }
        .onAppear {
            let url = URL(string: "https://api.pokemontcg.io/v1/cards")!
            
            self.fetch(url, defaultValue: [Pokemon]()) {
                self.pokemon = $0
            }
        }
    }
    
    func fetch<T: Decodable>(_ url: URL, defaultValue: T, completion: @escaping (T) -> Void) {
        
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
            .retry(1)
            .map(\.data)
            .decode(type: T.self, decoder: decoder)
            .replaceError(with: defaultValue)
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink(receiveValue: completion)
            .store(in: &requests)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key "cards" is an object array so you need to update  `Pokemon`  to as follows

```
struct Pokemon: Codable {
    var cards : [Card]
}
```

As the root of the JSON is a dictionary not an array, update the `.onAppear` function to

```
 .onAppear {
        let url = URL(string: "https://api.pokemontcg.io/v1/cards")!
        
        self.fetch(url, defaultValue: Pokemon(cards: [Card(id: "default", name: "default")])) {
            self.pokemon = $0
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Don't know how I missed that but there you go. Still learning but appreciate the help!